# Finding if two strings are similar

Tags: swift

I am trying to make an app for macOS in Swift which would take a folder with icons, find the apps that have similar names to icons and change the icons with the new one (I hope it's clear).

Anyway, I am new to Swift and I tried to make a function to know if two file name are similar (cause, for example, the icon name could be chrome_browser.svg while the app name is chrome.app). This function is supposed to look at every character of the two strings corresponding to two file names (one from the icon folder and one from the app folder) and increase a score every time a character is similar. Then we take the average of the score divided by the number of character we compared.

But every time I run it, the app stop responding and I don't get any result. I don't know if it's the operation for the average or the program itself that has a problem, but could anyone help me to find a way to solve this problem ?

Here's my code:

```swift
func similarity(fileName: String, appName: String) -> Double{
    var counter = 0
    var sameCharacterCounter = 0
    for fileNameCharacter in fileName {
        for appNameCharacter in appName {
            counter = counter + 1
            if fileNameCharacter == appNameCharacter {
                sameCharacterCounter = sameCharacterCounter + 1
            }
        }
    }
    let average = sameCharacterCounter/counter
    print(String(average))
    return Double(average)
}
```

Comment: You probably want the Levenshtein distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: There is no variable `moyenne`. Also note that `average` will be wrong since you are doing integer division.

Comment: @HangarRash Oh sorry i forgot to rename it while pasting it to stackoverflow. Basically the variable is called moyenne, it's french for average haha i just changed it here but forgot to change it everywhere. And thank you, I didn't know that, this may be one of the problems!

Comment: @HangarRash yes thank you so much, I didn't know this method existed, I'll see if it works with this post but I think it will